# (Educational Bureau doc)Is it grammatically correct for putting a "which" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct for putting a "which" in this sentence?

The government should designed the curriculum for all students until high school **which** all students will be having some subjects in common(Core subject) and some subject to be opt for(Elective subject)

Thank you~

Comment: The sentence is weird!

Answer (score 1):

You want to say "so that" instead of "which".

The government should design<del>ed</del> the curriculum for all students up until high school <del>which all students</del> so that they will <del>be having</del> have some subjects in common.

Then begin a second sentence where you distinguish between core subjects and electives.

Answer (score 0):

## In a word: No

There appear to be several issues with the sentence in question.  Whether or not you use 'which' is not the primary issue.  Please allow me to rephrase:

> The government should dictate the entire curriculum for all students until high school, when all students would then still have some common subjects (Core subjects) and also some subjects of their own choosing (Elective subjects.)

This is as close as I can come to what I believe to be your original intent.

I am a native U.S. English speaker.